# Databound Labels not reflecting changes after TableAdapter is filled?

Tags: c#, tableadapter, databound

I'm experiencing a strange behavior and I've spent many hours trying to figure out what's going on to no avail. The situation is that I have several labels that are databound to database fields, and that after I run a fill command on the tableadapters that these labels are databound to (which the data inside changes), the labels do NOT reflect the changes made in the tableadapter UNTIL I click another textbox-like control on the screen (ex. A datagridview cell, any textbox) OR clicking any button. Note that these controls have no code at all that relates to these labels.

This program is written in C# and unfortunately I'm not sure if any code snippets will help.

This program was inherited by me and made by another programmer so unfortunately I'm not too familiar with how it works, but I've been tasked with fixing this bug and keep coming up short. I have checked all the code in all the events that could possible relate to it and nothing is working. Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `Invalidate()` on the parent control of the labels.

Comment: Tried invalidating both the groupbox the labels are contained in, and also the form with no luck. I still must click a button, or click a text field in order for the labels to show their proper values